# iif statement to hide row visibility in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

Currently in a sub report I am pulling a list of data but it is showing the locations that have `0`. I have tried the following code in row visibility but it is still showing the `0` quantity locations:

```
=IIF(Fields!AvailableQty.Value > 0, false, true)
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for changes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything really wrong with your expression so here are a few suggestions.

You can simplify the expression to this

```
= Fields!AvailableQty.Value <=0
```

This will return true for instances where you want the row to be hidden so no need for an `IIF` statement.

If the rows you are trying to hide are grouped somehow then you will need to test the aggregated value like this

```
= SUM(Fields!AvailableQty.Value) <=0
```

If this does not help, edit your question to show the report design and the expression in the quantity. Also show where you tried to add the expression.

Another option might be to simply exclude these in the dataset query